# How can I achieve functionality similar to WPF's IValueConverter

Tags: qt, qml

In my `ListView` I've these:

```
ListView{
    id: listView
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    model: addContext.newLease.receivables
    delegate: ItemDelegate{
        width: parent.width
        topPadding: 0
        bottomPadding: 0
        contentItem:  RowLayout{
            Text{
                text: modelData.headId //mainContext.receivableHeads....name
                Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width / 2
            }
            Text{
                text: modelData.amount
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
            }
            PathButton{
                pathData: C.minusIcon
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
                hasToolTip: false
                onClicked: addContext.removeReceivable(listView.currentIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this I've some `Layout` issue BUT I'll ask about that later. Here in the `contentItem`'s first `Text`, I've a number `headId` and it presents that number in the `ListView` with that `modelData.headId` BUT I want to present the `name` instead.  The model, `addContext.newLease.receivables,` doesn't contain the `name`, it only has these properties:

```
class Receivable : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Property(int, leaseId)
    Property(int, headId)
    Property(int, amount)
};
```

`name` corresponding to the `headId` is in `mainContext.receivableHeads` which has these properties:

```
class Head : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Property(int, id)
    Property(int, controlId)
    Property(QString, name)
    Property(QString, description)
};
```

I want to get the `name` from `mainContext.receivableHeads` by matching the `headId` of `modelData` to the `id` of `mainContext.receivableHeads`.

**EDIT**

This:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QString headName(int headId){
    foreach(auto head, mvm->receivableHeads()){
        if(head->id() == headId)
            return head->name();
    }
}
```

along with this:

```
text: addContext.headName(modelData.headId) //modelData.headId //mainContext.receivableHeads.indexOf(modelData).name
```

as suggested by [Thomenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976276/thomenson), works. My `receivableHeads` is a tiny list, so it's a good candidate for javascript, is there any built-in javascript function that does this?

Well, I didn't know that javascript function like this:

```
text: {
    for(var i =0; i < mainContext.receivableHeads.length; i++){
        if(mainContext.receivableHeads[i].id === modelData.headId)
            return mainContext.receivableHeads[i].name
    }
}
```

also works!

Comment: What about using `Q_INVOKABLE` function that will take `headId` as parameter, go through `mainContext.receivableHeads`, find matching element and then return expected name?

Comment: @Thomenson, that'll work for sure BUT I expected some javascript function that does this. The QVector<QObject*> named `receivableHeads`, will contain at most 5/6 items.

Comment: I am afraid that I do not know any function like this that would be built-in but - if you prefer to have this logic at JS side - you can write such a function yourself.